# Shortcut to move point to beginning / end of current line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, emacs, keybindings

I use the [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/8511/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/C1/MC184F/MC184F?wid=572&hei=572&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400691344491)

The shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> (resp. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>) goes to the beginning (resp. end) of the buffer. The shortcuts <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> do not seem to have any effect.

Does anyone know how to set a shortcut to go to the beginning / end of current line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Emacs set of shortcuts:

- Beginning of the line <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- End of the line <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> should bring you back to the beginning of a document.

[This](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236) Apple support page describe a difference with what you are experiencing.

Try resetting your keyboard settings in the System Preferences > Keyboard

Also check this [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/31022/reset-mac-function-keys) question to reset FN keys.